# How to read the function pointer?

Tags: c++

How to interpret the following c++ declaration?

```
int (*(*x[2])())[3];
```

This is from the example present at [Type-cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming).

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is a helpful tool if you're struggling with types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an array of two pointers to functions that return pointer to array of type `int[3]` and do not have parameters.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
int ( *f() )[3] { return new int[2][3]; }
int ( *g() )[3] { return new int[4][3]; }

int main() 
{
    int (*(*x[2])())[3] = { f, g };

    for ( auto func : x ) delete []func();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _It is an array of pointers to functions that return ..._ must replaced with _It is an array of **2** pointers to functions that return_ right?

Comment: @Abraham There is no any need to explicitly say how many elements the array has.:) The record is self-descriptive.

Comment: Just for dummies such as me :)

Comment: This is a good answer but doesn't really answer the  question.

Answer (score 5):

The interpretation of the sample declaration in the question is present in the [Type-cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming) page linked.

```
int (*(*x[2])())[3];      // declaration of an array of 2 pointers to functions
                          // returning pointer to array of 3 int
```

So the actual question is not about that case in particular; but about how any C++ declaration shall be read.

You can infer all those details **starting at the declared name `x` and moving clockwise respecting parenthesis**. You will get to the description above:

> x is a an array of dimension 2 of pointers to functions that return a pointer to an array of dimension 3 of ints.

Better explained here as the ***Clockwise/Spiral Rule***: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html